# Failed to pass a string from Activity to Fragment

Tags: android, string, fragment

I want to pass a Serializable object from activity to fragment. But at fragment, **getArguments()** always retuns null. Then I try to pass a simple string value from activity to fragment, it still shows NullPointerExection.

Here is my Activity Class

```
public class FullProfile extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
private TabLayout tabLayout;
private ViewPager viewPager;
private Customer customer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_profile);

    tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
    viewPager = findViewById(R.id.myViewPager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    ProfileBasicFragment basic = new ProfileBasicFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("profile", "Hello Hello");

    basic.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.myViewPager, basic).commit();

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}

private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    FragmentAdapter fragmentAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 4);
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileBasicFragment(), "Profile");
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(new ProductFragment(), "Product");
    fragmentAdapter.addFragment(new WatchListFragment(), "Choices");

    viewPager.setAdapter(fragmentAdapter);

}
```

}

Here is my Fragment..

```
public class ProfileBasicFragment extends Fragment {

TextView t;
String s;

public ProfileBasicFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_basic, container, false);
    t = view.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);

    String s = getArguments().getString("profile");
    t.setText(s);

    return view;
}
```

}

And Here is the error

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I can't understand what's is my fault. Can you help me? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

the actual problem is when you initializing the viewPager.

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
...
fragmentAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileBasicFragment(), "Profile");
 //Problem is here
...
}
```

So send the data from here also or in your fragment do this

```
 if(getArguments()!=null){
 String s = getArguments().getString("profile");
 t.setText(s);
 }
```

Comment: Wow, I never think like that, Now I can pass my serializable object from activity to fragment like an object like that … fragmentAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileBasicFragment(profile), "Profile"); where profile is object. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same fragment twice, and sending the argument once in basic only(setupviewpager and basic). Either pass the argument in both case or add a null check before getting the string.

Comment: Now I can pass my serializable object from activity to fragment like an object like that … fragmentAdapter.addFragment(new ProfileBasicFragment(profile), "Profile"); where profile is object. Thank you :)